# Error with XSD restriction for Phone Number

Tags: xml, xsd

Here is my schema. I make it for an attribute in XML Doc.

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        targetNamespace="http://xml.netbeans.org/schema/ThueBao"
        xmlns:tns="http://xml.netbeans.org/schema/ThueBao"
        elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xsd:simpleType name="tTen">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="tSDT">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:ID">
        <xsd:pattern value="[0]{1}[0-9]{9}[0-9]*"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="tSDTGoiDi">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:pattern value="[0]{1}[0-9]{9}[0-9]*"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="tDiaBan">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="tThoiGianGoi">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:duration"/>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:complexType name="tThueBao">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="HoTen" type="tns:tTen"></xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="DiaBan" type="tns:tDiaBan"></xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="SoDienThoaiGoiDi" type="tns:tSDTGoiDi"></xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="ThoiGianGoi" type="tns:tThoiGianGoi"></xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="SDT" type="tns:tSDT"/>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:element name="DSThueBao">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="ThueBao" type="tns:tThueBao"></xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

And this is my xml.

```
<ns0:ThueBao SDT="0984224932">
    <ns0:HoTen>Pham Tuan Manh</ns0:HoTen>
    <ns0:DiaBan>Ha Noi</ns0:DiaBan>
    <ns0:SoDienThoaiGoiDi>01635981989</ns0:SoDienThoaiGoiDi>
    <ns0:ThoiGianGoi>PT2M</ns0:ThoiGianGoi>
</ns0:ThueBao>
```

On validating, NetBeans always show this error:

```
cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '0984224932' is not a valid value for 'NCName'. [15] 
cvc-attribute.3: The value '0984224932' of attribute 'SDT' on element 'ns0:ThueBao' is not valid with respect to its type, 'tSDT'. [15]
```

I have two phone numbers in my xml. The second is accepted, but the first. I have no idea how this could happen.
How can I fix this problems?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared SDT in terms of a pattern that restricts xs:ID, which in turn restricts xs:NCName; an xs:NCName must begin (loosely speaking) with a letter. It cannot begin with a digit (which is what your regular expression requires) - so no value will ever match this type.

The second phone number is defined as a restriction of xs:string, so that one is OK.

I don't know if you are aware that the pattern `[0]{1}[0-9]{9}[0-9]*` could be simplified to `0[0-9]{9,}`

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear explanation, Mr.Kay.
I edited my code and it work perfectly with <xsd:key> and <xsd:unique>.
One more time, thank you so much!